# POI apache, Função se tem o valor em uma célula apagar toda a linha

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

Preciso de uma ajudinha com a utilização do POI apache, no meu aplicativo preciso realizar uma consulta dentro de uma planilha, essa consulta verifica se na planilha existe um valor, essa consulta esta ok, abaixo vou colocar o código simulando um valor para que fique mais fácil e explicar.

**Segue o código da verificação;**

```
InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream(new File("sdcard/AperamApps/DBQ/historico/historico.xls"));
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);

            HSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);
            HSSFRow row; 
            HSSFCell cell;

            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

            while (rows.hasNext())
            {
                row=(HSSFRow) rows.next();
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

                while (cells.hasNext())
                {
                    cell=(HSSFCell) cells.next();

                    if (cell.getStringCellValue() != "google")
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Valor GOOGLE encontrado",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //PRECISO REMOVER A LINHA QUE POSSUI UMA CELULA COM  COM O VALOR GOOGLE
                    }

                }
                ExcelFileToRead.close();

                System.out.println();

            }
```

Meu código  consegue fazer a verificação porem preciso que se a condição retornar verdadeiro a linha onde está essa célula, tentei utilizar o `sheet.deleteRow(row);` dentro do if mais o aplicativo gera erro.

**Segue o logcat:**
http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3n/1449002824665.txt

```
12-01 15:34:37.851: I/dalvikvm(1632): Could not find method org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5, referenced from method org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.addPicture
12-01 15:34:37.851: W/dalvikvm(1632): VFY: unable to resolve static method 4982: Lorg/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils;.md5 ([B)[B
12-01 15:34:37.851: D/dalvikvm(1632): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0004
12-01 15:34:37.943: D/AndroidRuntime(1632): Shutting down VM
12-01 15:34:37.943: W/dalvikvm(1632): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4c4b648)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pro.kondratev.androidreadxlsx/matheus.arruda.aperam.controleDBQmestre.classe_master}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Specified row does not belong to this sheet
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Specified row does not belong to this sheet
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.removeRow(HSSFSheet.java:279)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at matheus.arruda.aperam.controleDBQmestre.classe_master.validar(classe_master.java:1608)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at matheus.arruda.aperam.controleDBQmestre.classe_master.ler(classe_master.java:682)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at matheus.arruda.aperam.controleDBQmestre.classe_master.onCreate(classe_master.java:203)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-01 15:34:37.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1632):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Experimente `row.removeAllCells();`

Comment: Boa noite, obrigado pela resposta e pela inclusão do logcat na pergunta, não consigo utilizar essa função, gera erro e manda renomear a parte "removeAllCells".

Comment: Esse código está ou é chamado no `onCreate()`?

Comment: Não, o `onCreate();` chama o metodo ler(); e o metodo ler(); chama metodo `validar();` que uma parte do código é esse que eu postei.

Comment: Em termos práticos é como se estivesse no `onCreate()`. Não sei o que poderá estar mal, até porque o método  [removeAllCells()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html#removeAllCells%28%29) existe na classe [HSSFRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html)

Comment: Estou achando estranho é que o `removeRow();` não consigo usar nem colocando o valor da linha que quero deletar, tentei usar o `removeCell` e também não dá se eu coloco `removeRow(1);` por exemplo, ocorre o erro e é sugerido o `removeRowBreak();`